# Sort html tables where its hidden contents appear on a different line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a html table, in that for each row  the additional elements are initially hidden `{ css : display :none ;}`. On toggling the first `<td>` element of each row the additional elements are displayed/hidden in a new line beneath its row ( its just like extension table in a new line beneath the corresponding row).  This works fine.

**The problem is**

I have to sort the table in ascending and descending orders such that the above table structure remains the same i.e each row is getting sorted according to corresponding header and also it displays the hidden items correspondingly in a new line beneath its row.

I have found [solutions](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable) where it sorts the table perfectly according to table headers but my problem is that I have to sort the tables and also to display the hidden contents like mentioned.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show the relevant part of your code? It will be easier to help

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you also include links to any solutions you have discovered during your research?

Comment: I found the basic table sorting here https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

Comment: @Nicole Great, now you just need to add any code thats specific to the problem. Please see Rory's link which explains how to do this

Comment: I have to do like the same but I have hidden elements with each row that are toggled in a new line .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/om57L3bf/

Comment: I just recreated a fiddle for a small part of code .. when you click Football News/ Tennis News , additional items are displayed. I have to sort the original table i.e the initial two rows based on the table header (Sports, ID , News Type) . Also after sorting the hidden values should be correspondingly there .

Comment: basic table sorting here kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable     Here it sorts the table according to tr tags. In my fiddle code , I have a div block associated after the tr tag. When I sort just using tr , the div blocks are getting distorted. Hope the scenario is a little clear to explain. Sorry fr me English.